# Using SimpleHttpFileServer with Gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm running some unit tests on Android, and I have to run an http server locally to get images from it during my tests. Until now, I'm using a python script that run the SimpleHttpServer of python, then call Gradle, then kill the server at the end.

I've found that there is a SimpleHttpFileServer that could be used in Gradle.
But I can't make it work. I found absolutely nothing about usage of this
class, except the doc here :

https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/plugins/javascript/envjs/http/simple/SimpleHttpFileServer.html

that doesn't say much. What is a Stoppable for instance? No doc about it.

When I try to use it, I have this error :
Could not find matching constructor for:
org.gradle.plugins.javascript.envjs.http.simple.SimpleHttpFileServer

Anyone here has played with that? Or do you see any other way to do it? Another idea was to run the python server from Gradle, then kill it at the end, probably using task.finalizedBy, but I didn't success either.

Any help on any of those methods would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Gérald